# Writing a map for this Monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, monad-transformers, category-theory

I have a monad transformer:

```
newtype ChoiceT f m a = ChoiceT (forall x . f x -> m x) -> m a
```

Now I think that this is a functor on the category of `Monad`s and I would like to make a map for this

```
mapChoiceT ::
  (n b -> m a)
  -- ^ Function from one monad to another.
  -- This is our morphism in the domain.
    -> (ChoiceT f m a -> ChoiceT f n b)
    -- ^ Function from lifted versions of the monads.
    -- This is our morphism in the image
```

However the implementation of this escapes me.  I was able to write a simpler version in which `n ~ m`:

```
lift2 ::
  (m a -> m b)
    -> (ChoiceT f m a -> ChoiceT f m b)
lift2 f m = ChoiceT (\ chooser -> f $ runChoiceT chooser m)
  where
    runChoiceT :: (forall x . f x -> m x) -> ChoiceT f m a -> m a
    runChoiceT chooser (ChoiceT runner) = runner chooser
```

But abstracting this up seems beyond me.  It occurred that this might be a *contravariant* functor, which would certainly make writing a covariant map hard, but I had no luck writing `contramapChoiceT` either.

```
mapChoiceT ::
  (n b -> m a)
  -- ^ Function from one monad to another.
  -- This is our morphism in the domain.
    -> (ChoiceT f m a -> ChoiceT f n b)
    -- ^ Function from lifted versions of the monads.
    -- This is our morphism in the image
```

Is this transformer a functor on the category of `Monad`s?  If it is how am I going wrong in implementing the map?  If it is not what counter example is there?

Comment: Side note: if you had a functor in the category of monads, the type of the morphism mapping would be `(m a -> n a) -> ChoiceT f m a -> ChoiceT f n a` -- changing `a` into `b` is a separate thing. (See also [the `MFunctor` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor).)

Comment: @duplode Thank you, I thought it was strange that the `MonadTrans` docs did that, but looking back they did not.  I must have made a copying error.  With your correction in mind things make more sense.

Comment: If it were `(forall x. m x -> f x) -> m a`  there would be some hope of this being a functor

Comment: Your code for `ChoiceT f m a` is a covariant functor with respect to `f`, not with respect to `m`.

Answer (score 3):

According to standard rules for determining co/contravariance, "a position is covariant if it is on the left side of an even number of arrows applying to it.". By examining the signature of `ChoiceT` we see the `m` parameter occurring in both contra- and co-variant positions. Thus `ChoiceT` is invariant in `m`.